# What is OOB workflow?

Tags: workflow

Can someone explain what OOB workflow and its definition?

I don't have experience in OOB workflow and I'm a newbie.
What is the definition of OOB workflow and OOB?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

‘Out of the box’ Workflows
SharePoint 2010 Standard and Enterprise include a selection of ‘out of the box’ workflows. These tools help you automate the most common business tasks – sharing and collecting feedback on documents.
[image]

List of OOB workflows:
[image]
Workflow Types
Windows Workflow Foundation supports two fundamental workflow styles. You can create workflows of either type for Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2010.

Sequential Workflows
A sequential workflow represents a workflow as a procession of steps that execute in order until the last activity completes. However, sequential workflows are not purely sequential in their execution. Because they can receive external events, and include parallel logic flows, the exact order of activity execution can vary somewhat.

[image]

State Machine Workflow
A state machine workflow represents a set of states, transitions, and actions. One state is denoted as the start state, and then, based on an event, a transition can be made to another state. The state machine can have a final state that determines the end of the workflow.

In the state machine style of workflow authoring, the author models the workflow as a state machine. The workflow itself consists of a set of states. One state is denoted as a start state. Each state can receive a certain set of events. Based on an event, a transition can be made to another state. The state machine workflow can have a final state. When a transition is made to the final state, the workflow is completed.

The following flowchart is an example of a state machine workflow.
[image]

[More details](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/635157/An-Introduction-to-SharePoint-2010-Workflows) and this [link](http://sharepoint-nirvana.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=164&Itemid=110)

Answer (score 2):

OOB (Out Of the Box) means what is already included in a particular version of SharePoint.

OOB workflows are workflows provided by SharePoint and are ready to use.

What workflows are available depends on the version of SharePoint you have (2007,2010,2013)(Foundation, Standard, Enterprise).

Activate site collection feature named Workflows to make them available for use.

Examples of OOB workflows: Approval, Collect Signatures, etc.

Comment: is there a list of workflow for 2007,2010,2013 to review?

Comment: Here's one [link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-foundation-help/about-the-workflows-included-with-sharepoint-HA102420739.aspx) for SP 2010

Answer (score 0):

we should explore further the workflows that come out of the box.

I introduced the Approval workflow.

- This is one of several workflows that are **available in SharePoint**.
- SharePoint provides six workflows out of the box that end users can configure on their sites.
- **You don’t need to be a programmer** to introduce valuable workflows into your organization.
- These workflows are available for adding to various SharePoint objects right **through the user interface and require little if any configuration**.

snapshot

[image]

- also sharepoint designer provide several actions for workflow, like create list items, update list items etc...

snapshot

[image]

Comment: Is there a list to review all available OOB workflow list?

Comment: updated my answer